# What is the url for product page in drupal commerce. Its admin url is : admin/commerce/products/2

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce for first time. I have created a product. I am unable to find the product view url. Its admin url is : admin/commerce/products/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal Commerce, you need to add product entities separately from product display pages. We simply create a product display node and reference all of our product entities using the product reference field.

See the docs for more help on this.

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products

Comment: Ok Great! Thanks! Its completely different from ubercart.